# Why do i get "undefined reference to `getlogin'"

Tags: c, shell, sh

Im trying to make a shell for my a uni project.
The first thing i want to add is the getlogin() function.
The problem is that it gives me an error and now i cant proceed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *getlogin();

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("TEST");
    char *user = getlogin();
    printf("%s", user);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is this:

PS D:\Visual Studio Code> cd "d:\Visual Studio Code\Sxoli\3o E3amino\Leitourgika Systimata" ; if ($?) { gcc mysh.c -o mysh } ; if ($?) { .\mysh }

c:\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\jayga\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsfUcBN.o:mysh.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `getlogin'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Why do you declare it yourself? And why does that declaration not match [the official declaration](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getlogin.html).

Comment: Also note that this function is a POSIX specific function (the `uni`part of the `unistd.h` file name is short for *Unix*). It exists only on systems like Linux or macOS. It doesn't exist on Windows. For Windows use the Windows-specific [`GetUserName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamea) function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because if i dont declare it i get a "implicit declaration of function" warning. If i declare it the "right way", i get the same problem as the post mentions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude im supposed to write a shell for Linux based systems. But im developing it in VSC on Windows.

Comment: Then you need a POSIX system to develop in. For example [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/), or a Docker container, or a virtual machine with a Linux install.